# transition effect when you hover on the li element

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to add an ease-in transition when one hovers on the `<li>` element, so that the `<ul>` element ca ease-in. Here's my html:

```
 <header>
        <nav>
            <div id="logo" style="color: white" class="try">Techflow</div>
            <label for="drop" class="toggle">Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <div class="pull-left">
                <ul class="menu">
                    <li>
                        <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Tech News</label>
                        <a href='@Url.Action("Index","Home")'>Tech News</a>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1" />
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("TechEvolution", "Tech")">Tech Evolution</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Tablets", "Tech")">Tablets</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Smartphones", "Tech")">Phones</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("InternetTV", "Tech")">Internet TV</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("UncappedInternet", "Tech")">Uncapped Internet</a></li>
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("ReviewAndAdvice", "Tech")">Reviews and Advise...</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

and here's my css:

```
header nav div ul li ul:hover{
    transition: ease-in 3s ease;
}
```

Comment: please use classes on your targets: `.target-ul` on the `<ul>`, rather than `header nav div ul li ul`

Comment: @ToniLeigh how does that answer my question?

Comment: it doesn't (that's why it's a comment not an answer) however, it's css best practice to avoid nested selectors and HTML entities as selectors so it would be advisable, it makes things much easier to manage and easier to re-use as well is decoupling the CSS from the HTML structure

Answer (score 0):

You have a selector with more 4 level of deep, is a good practice that not nested more 3 levels of deep because es more reusable, if you change any elements or add a element your selector not work

Your question, that proprieties should have the element father, and the elements li, have the property that you need change

Comment: it's best to avoid nested selectors altogether, they tie css to html structure

Answer (score 0):

first things first, your selector should be on the last `li:hover`

```
header nav div ul li:hover ul{
    /* CSS magic */
}
```

CSS doesn't have a ease-in transition, you're might be thinking of [jQuery fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)? Either way, [CSS transitions](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transition/) work like this:

```
transition: [property|all] [duration] [timing function] [delay];
```

For instance, if you'd want to ease in from hidden to visible:

```
header nav div ul li ul{
    transition: opacity .33s ease;
    opacity: 0;
}
header nav div ul li:hover ul{
    opacity: 1;
}
```